# Setting the audio Source in webrtc to speaker instead of mic

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, screensharing

I am writing webrtc app and I want to set the audio source while sharing screen to be the speaker "the internal audio of the machine" instead of sharing the mic. I am using a firefox as a browser.

Comment: Firefox still doesn't expose output devices, only Chrome does. And even in Chrome, it seems we can't set the output devices as constraint deviceId anymore.